# Is the behavior of unsigned(-0.0) defined in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, type-conversion, language-lawyer

C++11 4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

If the value is `-0.0`, is behavior defined?  It comes down to whether "the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type".  Zero could be represented.  Can negative zero?  In this context, are the two zero values distinguished, or not distinguished?

Comment: Negative zero is the same as positive zero, comparison-wise. Both have value zero...

Comment: Sure.  But that doesn't speak to whether the truncated value, if that value is -0.0, can be represented in the `unsigned` type.

Comment: There are two parts to this: One is "the truncated part". Two is representing that with an integral type. Do you agree that the truncated part of -0.0 is 0?

Comment: I think it's at least unclear, hence the question.  If the truncated value is indeed +0 here, then definitely behavior would be defined, to be sure.

Comment: Don't confuse types and values. The "truncated value" is just a number, in the abstract sense. It can't really be anything other than zero.

Comment: Additionally, don't confuse truncate (round to nearest int toward zero) and floor (round to nearest int toward negative infinity). truncate( -0.0 ) is 0.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The truncated value of `-0.0` is `0`, which is representable in integral types (including unsigned integral types).  There's no reason to suppose that the truncated value of `-0.0` and `0.0` are different, any more than the truncated values of `-0.25` and `0.3` are different.

Comment: "no reason to suppose...the truncated values of `-0.25` and `0.3` are different" Hmm, that's fair.  I'm not sure it's obvious in both cases, though, that removing the fractional component and getting zero value, will pick the positive-signed zero.  But of course this is all language-lawyer territory, mostly asked for fun.  :-)

Comment: @JeffWalden: There's no positive-signed zero _value_. Values, in this context, are mathematical values.

Comment: Some specs make clear that operations are upon mathematical values.  ECMAScript (JavaScript) is one (and explicitly clarifies how zeroes and signedness are considered).  I searched for language in C++ that would make similar statements but couldn't find any, so I'm not sure your assertion is fully justified.

Comment: At a minimum, unsigned integers are documented to obey modular arithmetic, which means that any non-infinity, non-NaN value should be representable in an unsigned integral type (modulo 2**bitcount).  The modulo representation for any zero (positive, negative, or non-signed), would be `0`.